# ASP.NET Zero (ABP) call simple action in controller

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, aspnetzero

I JUST want to call simple method from a controller but on calling, I get ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.
As I now this error is for services but I haven't any service for this controller or method!
I call class like this :

```
http://localhost:44302/ReturnBank/Verify?trans_id=b53e8b82-a849-4188-951a-bc7f060422cd&order_id=22&amount=5000&np_status=Unsuccess
```

Sample Code for Class is :

```
public class ReturnBankController : TimeSheetControllerBase
{
    private readonly SazPayPaymentGatewayConfiguration _SazPayConfiguration;
    
    public ReturnBankController(
        SazPayPaymentGatewayConfiguration SazPayConfiguration)
    {
        _SazPayConfiguration = SazPayConfiguration;
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> Verify(string trans_id, int order_id, int amount, string np_status)
    {
        if(np_status == "Unsuccess")
        {
            return View("../SazPay/PaymentCancel");
        }
        var SuccessUrl = _webUrlService.GetSiteRootAddress().EnsureEndsWith('/') + "Payment/paymentcompleted";
        var ErrorUrl = _webUrlService.GetSiteRootAddress().EnsureEndsWith('/') + "Payment/PaymentFailed";

        var inp = new SazPayConfirmPaymentInput
        {
            Order_id = order_id,
            Amount = amount,
            Trans_id = trans_id
        };

        var confirmTuple = await _SazPayPaymentAppService.ConfirmPayment(inp);


        if (confirmTuple.Item1)
        {
            Response.Redirect(SuccessUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect(ErrorUrl);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**PS: I think abp or aspnetzero magically convert my Controller/Actions to service!!! I want to stop this for one Controller or Action.**

Answer (score 0):

For the futures :
I found the answer!
After one hard day I found that wrong URL was the problem. I called HTTP but the right is HTTPS.

That was problem :(